# Способ укоротить условие WHERE в sql-запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, есть запрос, в котором я хочу наложить условие, чтобы он мне выдал только те строки, где `value > 500`:

```
select ...
    round((1 / (1 + exp((-1)*(... + ... + ... + ... + ...)))) * 1000) as value,
    ...
from table
where round((1 / (1 + exp((-1)*(... + ... + ... + ... + ...)))) * 1000) > 500
```

Есть ли возможность укоротить эту запись в условии `where`, чтобы не писать длиннющую строку, не прибегая к подзапросам вида `select * from (...) where value > 500`?

Comment: Можно создать представление, где это выражение будет одной из колонок результата, тогда вы сможете обращаться к нему по имени.

Comment: Чем не устраивает решение `select * from (...) where value > 500`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Однозначный *unknown field `value`*.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов приведенный в примере запрос в реальности в разы больше, неудобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ...
    round((1 / (1 + exp((-1)*(... + ... + ... + ... + ...)))) * 1000) as value,
    ...
from table
having value > 500
```

Comment: Эх, а я думал `having` только вкупе с Group By  можно.... интересно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В MySQL однозначно можно, а вот "старшие братья" могут не понять и обидеться.

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть в другой `SELECT`?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table
    WHERE round((1 / (1 + exp((-1)*(... + ... + ... + ... + ...)))) * 1000) > 500
) tmp
ON tmp.id = u.id
```

Comment: там изначальный запрос громадный, неудобно получится

Comment: @Denis таки какая разница какой там внутри запрос? в итоге же сводится лишь к одной операции сравнения `round((1 / (1 + exp((-1)*(... + ... + ... + ... + ...)))) * 1000) > 500`, а не его копирования. это всего лишь обёртка. не вижу проблем

Comment: Не совсем такой запрос, value тоже надо выводить само. Да и хотелось без подзапроса обойтись, чтобы с учетом его размера было читаемей.